# Importing Data from an Excel File into a Canvas App to create record in Dataverse

Tags: excel, powerapps, dataflow, powerapps-canvas

Hello,

I am building a power app. The user receives an excel sheet of a shipment every week and he has to create a shipment in the app. The excel sheet comes with a standard set of columns. I need some advice with pros and cons of the options I have.

Onedrive Excel File: Connect a Gallery to the excel file on Onedrive as a Datasource. When the user receives a new Excel file, he will go into the file on Onedrive and paste the new data. The app would refresh the data source with the Onvisible property of the screen. A create shipment button can then be used to create the records in the dataverse.

**Paste in Text Area:** Text input area on a screen within the app. Data is copied from the excel table and when pasted in this text area it will populate a Gallery on the same screen with the same data. A create shipment button can then be used to create the records in the dataverse.

**Dataflows:** Create a dataflow. I am not very comfortable with this because I am worried that it would break easily depending on how the flow is configured. I would appreciate help on the steps to configure the flow such that when a new excel sheet arrives it can be stored somewhere, the flow would detect the new file. Go into the file retrieve the data and create the record in the dataverse.

**Excel Power Apps Addin**: Configure the adin to connect to the dataverse and allow the user add and publish data. This is probably not best practice.

Any other ideas for solving this is most certainly welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311622/importing-data-from-an-excel-file-into-a-canvas-app-to-create-record-in-datavers